# Dataprep recipe fails to load with "Cannot read property 'expandScriptLines' of undefined"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

A recent update to dataprep sometime between August 7-10 has broken a number of our dataprep recipes.  Broken recipes fail to load with the error "**Cannot read property 'expandScriptLines' of undefined**".

The browser console shows the following error:

```
transformer error shown to user TypeError: Cannot read property 'expandScriptLines' of undefined
    at Sample.expandScriptLines (trifacta.4bb6b8ae549c19471518.bundle.js:2)
    at workspace-router.51e836ea8fb30fc60ca7.bundle.js:6
    at vendors~choose-storage-location~create-workspace~external-landing~missing-dataprep-permissions~passw~a3136f85.6e2bcf15c63385c98d0f.bundle.js:1
    at vendors~choose-storage-location~create-workspace~external-landing~missing-dataprep-permissions~passw~a3136f85.6e2bcf15c63385c98d0f.bundle.js:1
    at baseForOwn (vendors~choose-storage-location~create-workspace~external-landing~missing-dataprep-permissions~passw~a3136f85.6e2bcf15c63385c98d0f.bundle.js:1)
    at vendors~choose-storage-location~create-workspace~external-landing~missing-dataprep-permissions~passw~a3136f85.6e2bcf15c63385c98d0f.bundle.js:1
    at baseMap (vendors~choose-storage-location~create-workspace~external-landing~missing-dataprep-permissions~passw~a3136f85.6e2bcf15c63385c98d0f.bundle.js:1)
    at Function.map (vendors~choose-storage-location~create-workspace~external-landing~missing-dataprep-permissions~passw~a3136f85.6e2bcf15c63385c98d0f.bundle.js:1)
    at workspace-router.51e836ea8fb30fc60ca7.bundle.js:6
    at async Promise.all (/data/288523/index 1)
```

Here are some things we've observed:

- Loading a new sample of the data sometimes allows us to display the recipe and the preview.  However, refreshing the page or making any changes result in the same error.
- The bug *may* be associated with the presence of a `Union` operation in the recipe.

Our flows are primarily Excel/CSV based.  Here is a simple 3-step recipe that fails.  It takes 5 source CSVs as input:

[image: dataprep flow throws an error]

Any help would be appreciated as this has taken some of our most important flows offline.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit what your recipe does? The operations you use, the process

Comment: I added a screenshot of a recipe that is throwing the error.  It consists of a Union of 5 datasources followed by changing the type of a column and deleting some empty values.

Comment: Did you try removing steps 2 and 3 to conclude if the error is related to the union operation as you said?

Comment: Can you try replacing the datasets in source and try again?

Comment: A Trifacta support rep reached out to me directly and the problem magically solved itself a few days later.  I still don't know the root cause.  Thanks for all the suggestions, guys.